# What does Chrome's "Incognito Mode" do exactly?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, browser

I was under the impression that Chrome in Incognito Mode wouldn't accept or send cookies, since they could be used to identify you. When starting up Incognito Mode, I do have to re-log-in to gmail, etc. But the log-in stays active during the session.

So it seems to me that Incognito Mode maintains a separate, temporary store of cookies which get destroyed when you exit incognito mode. Does this mean that, if you browse in Incognito Mode all the time, it would have no benefit? Does Incognito Mode do anything else?

Comment: I think you should read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_mode)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It essentially sets the cache path to a temporary folder.  Cookies are still used, but everything starts "fresh" when the incognito window is launched.  This applies all storage, including Cookies, Local Storage, Web SQL, IndexedDB, cache, etc.

Of course Chrome also leaves pages out of the browser's history.

Comment: Something I've observed is that Chrome incognito does have at least some access to your cookies and browser history if you are signed into Chrome. Noticed this once when debugging a webapp. I suggest either using "Guest" account for Chrome or logging out of your Chrome account (assuming you ever logged in) before going incognito.

Comment: I have mentioned your name and @Mark in my answer

Comment: Signing in to Chrome is the devil!

Comment: I noticed that on Mac the temporary folder is removed, when chrome process is terminated, and not when you close it. Do you on what action is the temporary folder being removed on Windows?

Answer (score 17):

As a developer, it is also interesting to note that Incognito *DOES NOT* create a separate data partition for each window or tab.

All windows and tabs share access to the same cookies, so you can't create separate tabs to simultaneously log in as different users to one system that uses cookies to transmit authentication info.

Based on this, you still need to use a different browser to test this scenario.

Comment: This is very relevant to my life.

Comment: A bit unrelated to the issue at hand but if you need to log in as different users, a way around the incognito limitation is to use chrome profiles for each user account that you want to sign into simultaneously. This is because Chrome creates different data partitions for each chrome profile. 

Here's a link to how to find that data partition on your file system. TLDR, go to, chrome://version, and look at profile path, otherwise, read https://www.howtogeek.com/255653/how-to-find-your-chrome-profile-folder-on-windows-mac-and-linux/

Answer (score 9):

Just an important privacy note on @Jared Dykstra answer and @Mark comment.

> but everything starts "fresh" when the incognito window is launched.
>   This applies all storage, including Cookies

**Not 100% true**

Today I opened a new fresh chrome incognito window and requested youtube.com . but I surprisingly found that youtube is recommending some videos to me!!! How? based on what ? I'm supposed to be a very new client with fresh browser *- I noticed the recommended videos was based on the videos I usually watch while signed in to my google account from chrome or firefox -*

After investing the cookies I was shocked that chrome is sending these cookies to youtube.com along with the **very first request** send to youtube.com from a new freshly opened incognito window.

```
GPS
PREF
VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE
YSC
```

I guess youtube.com servers used these cookies to know who I'm and recommend videos for me based on them.

I checked Firefox and it **does not** do that, it starts the private windows with 100% empty cookies header!

Comment: agree with you. Chrome uses the existing cookies across incognitos and normal browser and makes its a stateful thing. Thats really a crap design ever expected from chrome guys

Comment: For me it was because I had openend different _windows_ (not tabs) and the cookie was reused which makes sense. Check if you don't have any more open incognito windows. When closing all of them the cookie jar started empty.

Comment: @buckley No, there was only 1 opened incognito window and Chrome still sends these cookies to youtube.com

Comment: Was the incognito process hung in the background or something, holding open the session but looking like a new one?  This would be an important finding if an working-as-designed chrome incognito really sends cookies from the regular profile.

Comment: Youtube is tracking your IP as well. This is why you sometimes can get recommendations based on what your family is watching.

Comment: If Youtube is tracking your IP, you should be able to find out using a different VPN server, of go use WiFi somewhere you've never been before. I.e. use a different IP.
Or, ipconfig /release and /flushdns, let it sit overnight fully shut down (not Windoze quick boot, Shift+PowerDown does that) then boot up the next day and see if your ISP gives you a different IP.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome's incognito mode sets the cache to a temporary folder. When you close the browser window the folder is deleted. So all your history, logins, and downloads are forgotten.

Incognito does not stop sites from keeping information about your visit nor does it hide the browsing from people using a tool like *Wireshark* to see what you are viewing.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is great. Just adding a note that Chrome has a setting to block ***third-party cookies** while in incognito mode*. See the description of the feature released May 19, 2020 in [Chrome 83.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9977812?hl=en)

> **Block third-party cookies in Incognito mode (Computer)**
>
> You can now block third-party cookies from ads and images on pages you visit in regular mode and in Incognito mode.

And more from [the product team](https://blog.google/products/chrome/more-intuitive-privacy-and-security-controls-chrome/):

> In addition to deleting cookies every time you close the browser window in Incognito, we will also start blocking third-party cookies by default within each Incognito session and include a prominent control on the New Tab Page. You can allow third-party cookies for specific sites by clicking the “eye” icon in the address bar. This feature will gradually roll out, starting on desktop operating systems and on Android.

[image: chrome version 83+ new tab in incognito mode offers a switch to block/unblock third-party cookies, and an "eye" icon to inform you when third-party cookies are blocked]

Comment: I noticed that when signing into an Okta app that the "sid" cookie is still being set even when in Incognito mode.

Answer (score -4):

If you don’t want Google Chrome to save a record of what you visit and download, you can browse the web in incognito mode.

A detailed link of what Chrome itself says

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en

Comment: as the question suggests the questioner is aware about the incognito mode but seeks help regarding how it works internally and how / how long any data is stored.