# Error in JavaScript/Jquery code: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need help. Been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why this code is erroring at the last IF statement... If i delete

```
if(tagsfield && editor && titlefield && node_select !==="None"){
$("#postform").submit();
    }
```

Then the javascript/jquery loads. When included...all of my other java does not load and i get a..
"uncaught syntax error: unexpected identifier", at the jquery submit line..

Full code..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var node_select  = $("#assigned").text();

$( "#submit" ).click(function() {
var editor =    $('#edit').froalaEditor('html.get');    
var tagsfield = $('#mySingleField').val();
var titlefield = $('#title').val();

if(!editor){
document.getElementById("content_validate").innerHTML = "<h5><span class=\"label label-danger label-validate\">Required</span></h5>";

}
if(!tagsfield){
document.getElementById("tag_validate").innerHTML = "<h5><span class=\"label label-danger label-validate\">Required</span></h5>";
}

if(!titlefield){
document.getElementById("title_validate").innerHTML = "<h5><span class=\"label label-danger label-validate\">Required</span></h5>";
}
if(node_select == "None"){
document.getElementById("folder_validate").innerHTML = "<h5><span class=\"label label-danger label-validate\">Required</span></h5>";
}

if(tagsfield && editor && titlefield && node_select !=="None"){
$("#postform").submit();
}

}); 
});
```

The #postform is confirmed in my code...For some odd reason. This code worked fine locally and only started to fail once i put it on the server.

```
<form action="" name ="arts" id="postform" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control"   placeholder="Title" value="">
<input name="tags" id="mySingleField" value="apple,banana,pear" type ="hidden"> 
<textarea id="edit" name="content" ><!--blah blah--></textarea>
</form>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" id="submit">Post</button>
```

Comment: `!===` should be `!==`

Comment: Can you show the html?

Comment: *"This code worked fine locally..."* No, it didn't.

Comment: @RaxWeber: There's no need, Andreas already pointed out the typo.

Comment: His code is !== not !===. Check the actual code.

Comment: Just added the html...

Comment: Whats really wierd is that if i comment these lines out.. Error still appears against them..But if i delete them from the code. Then the page loads good.

Comment: @RaxWeber the test appears twice in the question - in the first instance it's `!===`.  Given that it's different, there's no way to tell what's in the *actual* code.

Comment: @Leo505 that would happen if the browser is caching the js.  Make sure you use ctrl-f5 or the browser tools to ignore cache.

Comment: @freedomn-m It is presumable; he typed the first instance, but copy-pasted the whole code after.

Comment: @RaxWeber that would be a sensible conclusion.

Comment: Sorry for the inconsistent code...I was in the midst of testing different versions..It is using !==
And i am browsing in icog' mode to avoid cache issue

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed.
I double checked my cache and i was still storing the older version of some files..So the changes were not taking place.
I cleared all browsing data and that resolved the cache issue.
I was using icog mode on chrome so not sure what happened there.

Thanks for all your guys/girls help
Much appreciated.

Comment: As [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33620755/3836051) explains, the browser still caches in incognito mode, but in a separate, temporary folder that is being deleted when you close the last incognito window. So to really avoid the cache you can just close all incognito windows, open a new one to see your code working and you'll be sure not to use an old version of it.